# Can't post param id in NodeJS server on Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, heroku, ionic-framework

I'm currently developing an Ionic application and writing the server in NodeJS with Express and hosting it on Heroku. However, it doesn't correctly post the desired route. I get this error when I test it on Chrome:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) https://[SERVER NAME].herokuapp.com/rooms//messages
```

The server should be posting the id parameter in between /rooms/ and /messages/, but it isn't. Here's the server-side code:

```
     var messages = []; //make an array to hold messages
     var rooms = [];

     app.get('/rooms', function(req, res) {
        res.json(rooms);
    });

    app.get('/rooms/:id/', function(req, res){
        var room = rooms[req.params.id];
        res.json(room);
    });

    app.post('/rooms', function(req, res) {
        var newRoom = {
            timestamp: new Date()
            //username: req.body.username
        };
        rooms.push(newRoom);
        res.json(rooms);
        console.log(rooms);
    });



    app.get('/messages', function(req, res) {  //req = request, res = response
        res.json(messages);
    });

    app.get('/messages/:id', function(req,res) {
        var message = messages[req.params.id];
        res.json(message);
    });

    app.post('/messages', function(req,res){
        var newMessage = {
            message:req.body.message,
            username:req.body.username,
            timestamp: new Date()
        };

        messages.push(newMessage);
        res.json(messages);
    });
```

Why isn't it properly posting the correct route? When I check the logs on Heroku it does not appear to be getting the :id for the rooms.
Thank you.

EDIT: Here are the github repos for further reference:
Client: https://github.com/dukeeagle/ttt-client
Server: https://github.com/dukeeagle/ttt-server

Comment: `https://[SERVER NAME].herokuapp.com/rooms//messages` is that correct request? Look at `/rooms//messages`

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov What do you mean? [SERVER NAME] is a placeholder, of course. When I attempt to navigate to `/rooms//messages` nothing appears.

Comment: You have to declare `/rooms/:id/messages` route in express as `app.get('/rooms/:id/messages', ...`. Then try to navigate to `/rooms/123/messages` and you have to get correct response.

Comment: @DmitriyLoskutov - Just tried that. I got the same 404 error. However, I also noticed that when I'm in `http://localhost:8100/#/rooms/` to view a room, the route isn't `#/rooms/0/` or of the like. It looks like it's not even getting the rooms :id in the first place. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed it!
Here's the correct routing method for those who are interested:

```
app.get('/rooms', function(req, res) {  //req = request, res = response
        var user = users[req.params.id];
        var userRooms=[];

        res.json(rooms);
    });

    app.get('/rooms/:id', function(req,res) {
        var room = rooms[req.params.id];
        res.json(room);
    });

    app.post('/rooms', function(req,res){
        var newRoom = {
            name:req.body.name,
            id:rooms.length, 
            username:req.body.username,
            timestamp: new Date(), 
            messages: [],
            players: []
        };
        rooms.push(newRoom);
        res.json(rooms);
    });

    app.post('/rooms/:id/messages', function(req, res){
        var room = rooms[req.params.id];
        var newMessage = {
            username:req.body.username,
            timestamp: new Date(),
            message: req.body.message
        }
        room.messages.push(newMessage);
        res.json(room);
    });

    app.post('/rooms/:id/players', function(req, res){
        var room = rooms[req.params.id];
        var newPlayer = {
            timestamp: new Date(),
            player: req.body.username
        };
        room.players.push(newPlayer);
        res.json(room);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I init express server with that code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('/rooms/:id/messages', function (req, res) {
   var id = req.params.id;
   res.send('Hello, moto! ' + id);
});

app.listen(2345, function () {
 console.log('server started');
});
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:2345/rooms/123/messages` I see at the page string `Hello, moto! 123`

Try to remove your other routes for tests, maybe it is get some conflicts.

Comment: This isn't quite what I'm looking for. The app must navigate to `http://localhost:8100/#/rooms/0/` and see a list of all of the messages sent to that specific room. The problem is that the :id for rooms isn't being posted by the server.

Comment: The first argument in `app.get` or `app.post` should be `path` not `hash` of request URL. In your case path is `'/'`. So, you can use `app.get('/', ...` and then parse hash part of originalURL. See more about it http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#router.METHOD

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. What do you mean by path or hash? The document that you linked doesn't mention either of these two things.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Locator. Hash is the part of URL after `#`

Comment: So what am I to do now that I know that? After further examining the console I found out that it was able to get the id of each room but it isn't able to `POST` it. What am I to do?

Comment: Your client side try to navigate to `http://localhost:8100/#/rooms/0/`. But your server side only supports `http://localhost:8100/rooms/0/`. So, you have to change your routing on client or your routing on server side :)

Comment: Removing the hash is not an option since I am using Ionic. That is not the issue here. I have created other applications in Ionic that allow for hashes on the client-side. What should I do about the inability to `POST`?